# To find a version for your pc check with the software publisher install mongodb

Tags: mongodb, installation, nosql

I want to install MongoDb on windows 8 but when i try to run `C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe`iget this error:

```
To find a version for your pc check with the software publisher.
```

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer to this question by asking on their support forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which version did you download and install?  If you have 64-bit Windows 8, you should [download and install the build marked with "2008R2+".](http://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.4.1.zip)  Their [download page](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) indicates that:

> The Windows 2008+ build uses newer features of Windows to enhance
>   performance. Use this build if you are running with 64-bit Windows
>   Server 2008 R2, Windows 7, or greater.

If you are using 32-bit Windows 8, you should [download the 32-bit Windows version.](http://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-i386-2.4.1.zip)  Of course the 32-bit version has some limitations, such as a max database size of 2GB.

Answer (score 1):

Though the documentation page tells that 2008R2 works on windows 7 or greater, It didn't work on Windows 8.  I have installed regular 64 bit version http://www.mongodb.org/dr/downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.4.2.zip/download and it did work.